# How to make a welcome screen

Tags: android, loading

Hello I'm a new android developer.

I want to do a welcome page which can display program logo [ full screen image] and loading progress of my main program.

My main program has to load a webpage. My question is how to display the web-loading progress of the main program on the welcome page, while showing the welcome page until the download is completed.

Answer (score 1):

here is a tutorial how to create a splashscreen

http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html#more-561

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the Android 'spinning circle' while loading, have a look at the official tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog). It gives the code to show a pop-up loading window, and the code for how to use multiple threads (e.g. one thread to show the loading animation, another to download the information from the web).